# Jasper 2 compile the same jsp file and generate different jsp.class

Tags: java, jsp, ant, compilation, el

We use ant and jasper 2 engine to compile the jsp files.

Let's say we have jsp1 from A branch and jsp2 from B branch, the A and B branch have the same version of source code, so basically jsp1 and jsp2 have the same content.

I notice jasper 2 compile those two jsp files and generate different jsp.class. I can tell by checking the checksum of those two jsp.class.

So my 1st question is what causes this problem, 2nd question is how to make jsp compilation every time generates the same jsp.class.

One observation is some jsp.class files are the same which they do not have EL, so is EL the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use checksum to check your .jasper files since they contain generated data. If there is problem with one of those files.

The way I checked it was simply `strings` command from 2 different .jasper builds of the same source.

You should just ignore it.